# Is possible to place all MVC areas inside one folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'd like to place all my areas inside the **Areas** folder (shown in the picture below).

Is it possible to achieve that? If so, what type of routing changes do I need to do to avoid any browser errors?

[image]

Comment: Just create one area, and put everything together. You can use the RouteAttribute to map whatever you want : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx

Comment: @Thomas I'd prefer to avoid routing attributes because they add additional complexity to the controller configuration. I would need to remember to add that constantly as a default selection

Comment: I totally understand this approach. There is a new attribute InheritedRouteAttribute that allows you to define a base class for your controller with a default route. See the article: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-mvc-52